# Is there any elemental pieces template (blank) which together forms a corrugated box of desired size, or is there anything similar to it?

Tags: materials, design, material-science, packaging-engineering

We run a corrugated box business. I have known elements in chemistry; I was thinking, whether similar to them, there are any elemental corrugated box templates (dieline; keyline) which together form a box of desired size. Or anything similar, where template or design, allows formation of desired sized box.

Comment: I expected packaging-engineering tag; it is not there.

Comment: "Elemental?"  I don't think cardboard is on the periodic table.,

Comment: If the box can be formed from one flat panel then the opened out plan can be based on one, or more, dimensions then it can be folded. But in pieces? don't think it will have the strength...

Comment: there is more than one way to cut cardboard to make a box ... take apart some boxes to see how they're constructed

Comment: If you have sizes, structural requirements translated to how much the overlap needs to be at joints, etc, you can create a template formula pretty easily.  Should be similar to sheet metal design- taking a desired end result, applying extensions or reductions for how it folds, and appropriate gaps and overlaps result in a flat pattern.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to spec elementary pieces of a box:

There are faces. They are made of some thickness of cardboard and they are flat.

There are bends.  These are not flat and through the process of folding exhibit a slightly different length flat and relaxed than bent and under stress.  In sheet metal a K factor, or other compensation is applied to calculate the flat length.

There are joints.  These are like faces but they get bonded to faces (via glue, staples, etc).  In sheet metal, it isn't uncommon to use similar flanges for riveted, welded, or bolted connections to faces.

Finally, there are reliefs.  These are extra removals of material to make bending work.  If you unfold a cardboard box, this would be the gaps between adjacent flaps.  In sheet metal, they might just be a square or circular cutout near the bend rather than going the full length of those flaps; doing the same in cardboard is possible, but removing more material reduces weight (and cardboard is easy enough to cut and recycle).

Put combinations of these together to meet size, structure, and assembly requirements of your box.